# Allow editing of own content but not show 'node settings' block

Tags: 8, users

Hello all and happy new year! ..

I have a question that I thought would have been answered before, but could not find anything..

I want users of a certain role to be able to edit their own content (nodes of a specific content type).  This all works well.  However, they can also see the 'Node Settings' option, which is a block on the right hand side with settings such as: 'CSS class(es), layout box' etc.  (see picture below)

[image: node settings]

I don't want the above settings to be available to the particular role, although that role would have the right to edit the node - in other words, I want them to be able to alter **content**, but not be able to mess around with css classes, layout boxes and anything like that ...

Ideally, I would like that **whole 'Node Settings' block to be available only to administrators, and not to users of any role** - even if they do have permissions to edit the content of that particular node.

I looked carefully into permissions and searched the web, but could not find anything ... My feeling is that this should be done as it must be quite a frequent case ..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is quite easy using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` like this,

```
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
  if (in_array('YOUR_ROLE', $roles)) {
    unset($form['...']);
  }
}
```

if you don't know what the name of the element is called, try to find it using kint($node) if you have devel installed.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess this must be the best way. However, I don't know yet how to play with those functions - I guess I really need to learn the Drupal API and study how to create custom modules (this is what you do with the above code, if I am not mistaken). I have found some info on the web, but if you know a good tutorial please let me know. Documentation pages are quite bewildering for a newbie like myself. Anyway, I think I might just disable the settings for the CT config page for the time being. Thanks again for your help..

Comment: This guide is really good https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules

Comment: The code I wrote you need to add in your custom module in a MODULENAME.module file, that will be a PHP file